# Why are plotted predicted values and marginal effect different?

Tags: r, ggplot2, predict

I am working with an LMER model with the following specification:

```
m12 <- glmer(vote_share ~
              previous_vote_share + coal + coalshare*cabpol.g + coalshare*cabpol.s + coalshare*cabpol.e +
              (1|country_name) + (1|party_name),
            data = df)

mtable(m12)

Calls:
m12: lme4::lmer(formula = vote_share ~ previous_vote_share + coal + 
    coalshare * cabpol.g + coalshare * cabpol.s + coalshare * 
    cabpol.e + (1 | country_name) + (1 | party_name), data = df)

======================================
  (Intercept)               3.977**   
                           (1.429)    
  previous_vote_share       0.689***  
                           (0.025)    
  coal                     -2.360*    
                           (0.967)    
  coalshare                 0.029     
                           (0.016)    
  cabpol.g                  0.615     
                           (0.482)    
  cabpol.s                 -0.383     
                           (0.354)    
  cabpol.e                 -0.425     
                           (0.454)    
  coalshare x cabpol.g     -0.016     
                           (0.011)    
  coalshare x cabpol.s      0.008     
                           (0.008)    
  coalshare x cabpol.e      0.022*    
                           (0.011)    
--------------------------------------
  Var(residual)            30.038     

--------------------------------------
  Var(~1|party_name)        8.633     

--------------------------------------
  Var(~1|country_name)      3.833     

--------------------------------------
  Total                  1390         
  party_name              284         
  country_name             37         
--------------------------------------
  Log-likelihood        -4469.922     
  Deviance               8939.844     
  AIC                    8965.844     
  BIC                    9033.925     
======================================
```

I want to plot the interacted effect of `cabpol.e` and `coalshare`.

So here are the predicted values of `vote_share` (the dependent variable) with these two variables:

```
df$pred.vote_share <- predict(m12)

ggplot(df, aes(y = pred.vote_share, x = cabpol.e, color = coalshare)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_gradient2(midpoint=50, low="blue", high="red", space ="Lab") +
  geom_smooth(method='lm', se=F)
```

[image]

(On a sidenote question, how can you add different trendlines for subsets of continuous data? I would like to have a line for `coalshare >= 67`, `coalshare > 33 & coalshare < 67` and `coalshare <= 34`.)

But then, when I use `ggpredict` function, from `ggeffects` package, the effect seems very different:

```
me <- ggpredict(m12, terms = c("cabpol.e", "coalshare"))
plot(me)
```

[image]

Shouldn't the predicted values be similar to the marginal effects illustrated by `ggpredict`? Is there something wrong in the code that would explain this disparity? Thanks!

Comment: If you can deviate from ggplot2, have a look at the __effects__ package. The author is John Fox, one of the R core members.

Answer (score 0):

`predict()` without the `newdata`-argument returns the predicted value for each observation, based on the values of the other variables for each observation.

`ggpredict()`, however, calculates predicted values for `cabpol.e` at representative values of `coalshare` (your two variables in `terms`). For `coalshare`, since it is continuous, mean +/- 1SD are chosen as "representative values" (see [this vignette](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/introduction_effectsatvalues.html) for more details). All other model predictors are held constant (at their mean or reference level). However, you can add the raw data points by using the `add.data = TRUE` to the `plot()` call, see [this example](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/introduction_plotmethod.html#add-data-points-to-plot-1).

> I would like to have a line for coalshare >= 67, coalshare > 33 & coalshare < 67 and coalshare <= 34.)

You cannot plot lines for a *region* of values (e.g. colshare > 33 & coalshare < 67). That's why `ggpredict()` chooses "representative values". If you look at the values for the mean and +/- 1 SD, that these values (18.1, 52.3, 86.5) look like being in the middle of your desired ranges, so these indeed might reflect the lines you're looking for quite well.

If you want to use other functions than `predict()` (which is used by `ggpredict()`), you can replace `ggpredict()` by `ggeffect()` (which calls functions from the *effects* package) or `ggemmeans()` (which uses the *emmeans* package). So you can utilize their functionality, but create ggplot-plots.